# Error 5 vba, invalid call when looping through a recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to create a string to paste to the body of an email. Getting an Error 5 invalid call when looping through a record set. It goes through the first record fine, but once it gets to the second record, it throws the error.

```
Do While Not recSet.EOF
   For intCtr = 0 To recSet.Fields.Count - 1
      strData = strData & recSet.Fields(intCtr) & Space(25 - Len(Nz(recSet.Fields(intCtr))))
Next
   strData = Trim(strData) & vbCrLf
   recSet.MoveNext
   Debug.Print strData
Loop
```

It's supposed to paste the results from a query into the body of the email.

Comment: Have you step debugged? I tested your code and do not get the error. Edit question to post rest of procedure (opening recordset) and sample data.

Comment: I have step debugged and once it gets to the second record, it throws the error. It’s just a simple recordset.

Comment: I cannot replicate error. However, suggest you move the Debug.Print to outside the recordset loop. If you don't want to provide info as requested, cannot help further.

Comment: I’ll run some more tests and get back to you.

Comment: It errors on strData = strData & recSet.Fields(intCtr) & Space(25 - Len(Nz(recSet.Fields(intCtr))))  and the value is 1

Comment: Still cannot replicate error and therefore do not have solution.

Comment: If I remove the Space() function it doesn't error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are subtracting the length of the field from 25, but what if the length is say 30? You would need to determine the length of field. Could you post more of your code? It would help greatly.

Comment: That's it. The length of one of the strings is longer than 25. Not sure why I didn't catch it. Thank you so much for your help!